# How to change the systemd timeout in centos

Tags: centos7, systemd

The default start timeout for systemd is `90s`. I want to change it to `300s`. So I change the `DefaultTimeoutStartSec` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`

```
# vi /etc/systemd/system.conf
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
```

But how can I make systemd reload the `/etc/systemd/system.conf`? If only change the file, the timeout does not change.

```
# systemctl show service -p TimeoutStartUSec
TimeoutStartUSec=1min 30s
```

Answer (score 9):

`systemctl daemon-reexec` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

there are only a few properties that you can set thru "set-property" command.

you can get a version of your systemd thru command:

```
systemctl --version
```

then you need to update it to get latest commands like "cat" with:

```
sudo yum update systemd -y
```

after that you can see stuff that overrides your DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s run:

```
systemctl cat <service>
```

Then you need to create a {service}.service file to override your settings with information from [Service] section from systemctl cat {service} command and restart daemon after that:

```
echo "[Service]
TimeoutSec=15min
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/<service> start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/<service> stop
ExecReload=/etc/rc.d/init.d/<service> reload" > /lib/systemd/system/{service}.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```